# I want to check the value of the input field in the database and put the text of the second column of this value to another field using laravel

Tags: javascript, database, laravel

I want to check the value of the input field in the database and put the text of the second column of this value to another field using laravel.

html code

```html
    <input type="text" name="ccode[]" id="target" class="td-size" autocomplete="off" >
    <input type="text" name="cname[]" id="codename" class="td-size">
```

javascript code

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#target').change(function(){
      var code = $('#target').val();
      if(code !== null){
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ route('getcodename') }}",
            data: {code:code},
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
            });
         }else{
                alert("no");
            }
    });
    });
        </script>
```

controller:

```
    public function getcodename(Request $request)
     {
     $codename = DB::table("communitydata")
     ->where("code",$request->code)
     ->pluck("c_name","cd_id");
     return response()->json($codename);
     }
```

web Route

```
Route::get('getcodename',[DropdownController::class, 'getcodename'])->name('getcodename');
```

database screenshot:
[image]

Form Screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
$(this).closest('#codename').val(data);
```

It will find closest element with id `codename` and change its value.

[Jquery closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: $('#target').change(function(){
  var code = $('#target').val();
  if(code !== null){
     $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
  url: "{{ route('getcodename') }}",
  data: {code:code},
  success:function(data){
     $('#codename').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     $('#codename').val(data);
     $('#target').closest('#codename').val(data);
   alert(data);
  }
  });
    }else{
   alert("no");
  }
});
    </script>                                                                                                                                       this not work

Comment: Here data is the value which you want to set. Is it the same?

Comment: yes,   You check the controller code to see if it is correct.